# PHP & MySQL - not inserting into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got an problem in my code. The insert is not working. The code is below.

HTML:

```
<form action="staff.php" method="post" class="center" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <input type="text" placeholder="headline of the news" name="title">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
    <select name="side" value="side">
        <option>Left</option>
        <option>Header</option>
        <option>Main</option>
        <option>Ending</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="desc" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="full news" name="desc"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Post">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("DB SERVER", "DB USER", "DB PASS", "DataBase");
$charset = mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
    $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $side = $_POST['side'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contents (title, image, side, description) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$image', '$side', '$desc')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "<p class='success'>Image uploaded successfully</p>";
    } else {
        $msg = "<p class='error'>There was a problem uploading the image</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Everything is fine except the *inserting into database*.

Comment: Have you tried with print query and manually paste in database if its inserting or not?

Comment: Nope not working.

Comment: This code is wide open to SQL injection, you could be executing *anything* in that SQL code.  What is the actual runtime value of `$sql`?  If `mysqli_query()` is returning `false`, what does `mysqli_error($db)` tell you?  Chances are if you fix the SQL injection problem, the current problem becomes moot.

Comment: `print_r($sql);` execute this line and update the question

Comment: See [How to get mysql errors in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments)

Comment: Could you please update the code to show what kind of error there is in the mysql command? if(!$result){ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add concatenation in the query like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contents (title, image, side, description) 
        VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."', '".$side."', '".$desc."')";
```

Comment: This is not the issue since double quoting accepts variables inside, so echo "I am $var" will print out whatever in var is.

Comment: `print_r($sql);` execute this line and update the question

Comment: Anyone looking at this answer should note that it is open to SQL Injection attacks, and should really be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead!

Comment: @Soumya: Note that it's likely to be by coincidence alone that this is "working", because this is functionally no different from what you have.  The code presented in this answer is still fundamentally "broken" in the same way your original code is, in that you blindly execute any SQL code your users send you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, it should work.

But you're allowing SQL injections, so if you send within parameter single quotes your query will not work as expected and will throw out an error...

You should first:

- clear passed strings (use mysqli_real_escape_string), http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- Check if mysqli_query executed if not then use `mysqli_error` to find out what error caused your query to not work: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1):

Use as

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("DB SERVER", "DB USER", "DB PASS", "DataBase") or die(mysqli_error("Could not connect to Database"));
mysqli_query($db,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
    $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['title']);
    $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $side = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['side']);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['desc']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contents (title, image, side, description) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$image', '$side', '$desc')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
       $msg = "<p class='success'>Image uploaded successfully</p>";
    }else{
       $msg = "<p class='error'>There was a problem uploading the image</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = "INSERT INTO contents VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."', '".$side."', '".$desc."')";`

This could be a shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contents (title, image, side, description) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."', '".$side."', '".$desc."')";
```

The problem is here use this.